# Rollback Settings

Tags: 20.04, system-settings

I wanted to import my entire wallpapers folder in the background options under settings. I forgot there were a lot of files in there, over 3000+. When I imported it, the app crashed and I am now unable to access settings. Now, every time I try to open settings there is a dialogue box that says that Settings is not responding, and I have to either wait or force quit.

Is there a way to rollback what I did?

Comment: First try to log out then in to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Try to reinstall settings using the following commands:- `sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center` ---then---  `sudo apt-get install unity-control-center`. If the problem persists, use purge instead of remove. Note- It will reset all desktop configurations.

Comment: @vanadium Tried restarting the computer, issue persists.

Comment: @Master_Nachi Is there anything else that will be reset?

Comment: your wifi, bluetooth, network settings etc. but you can change it again after reinstalling.

Comment: @Master_Nachi I tried removing it, but it says that control center was never installed.

Comment: Try `gnome-control-center` instead of `unity-control-center`

Comment: @Master_Nachi Tried gnome instead of unity and it worked. But heres the problem: I tried remove and purge but both of them failed to alter the settings. When I installed the control center back, it still had the wallpapers in the background option, so I'm assuming it never removed them from there.